# ERROR: duplicate key value violates unique constraint "constraint_name"

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have been recieving the following error:

```
ERROR: duplicate key value violates unique constraint "child_pkey"
DETAIL: Key (child_id)=(4) already exists.
```

This is the query I tried to run:

```
INSERT INTO child
VALUES(4, 'Max','Roy','M', 2) ;
```

for child_id=4 i have not inserted any data as for now but I am still recieving this error.
Just to cross check I did check the table, and there was no existing entries for child_id = 4
I will be grateful if anyone could help.

Comment: Two possibilities: A row with id 4 exists, which you would see with `select * from child where id = 4` or there is a trigger generating the duplicate. (You should always name the columns in an insert, by the way (`INSERT INTO child (id, x, y, z) VALUES (...)`. And technical IDs should get generated (`id INT GENERATED ALWAYS AS IDENTITY` anyway.)

Comment: There is another possibility; *If this is part of a series of `inserts`*. A prior insert could already have created the value.  That would generate your error. If you run query for the offending value both before and afterthat process, neither would find would not find it as both would be discarded on the error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to truncate that entry, if ik keeps doing the same, launch the table query, drop all the table and create it again.